# Voice Recongintions in all the browers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to find a voice recognition library  in JavaScript but unfortunately i couldn't find any options and i really don't want to limit my project to only one browser.All the thing i could find were based on the chrome tool of voice recognition

Comment: https://idmnyu.github.io/p5.js-speech/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `webkitSpeechRecognition`. It's going to be hard to find something that all browsers are compatible with, but, as you can see below, `webkitSpeechRecognition` works mainly with Chrome and Safari, which are the two main browsers.

[image]